# Matlab Fill previous value if missing value (or zero)

Tags: matlab, interpolation

I have a vector containing a time series with different values and some missing values inbetween that are set to zero:

```
X=[0,0,2,0,5,0,0,0,4,0];
```

I want to create a new vector where the missing values (zeros) are populated by the previous value if one exist so that I get a new vector looking like:

```
Z=[0,0,2,2,5,5,5,5,4,4];
```

I have been browsing through the Matlab help and forums like this to find a neat and suitable function that would solve this for me with a one line solution or similar, but I have failed to do so. I can solve the problem through a few different steps according to below but I am guessing that there must be a better and easier solution available?

Current solution:

```
X=[0,0,2,0,5,0,0,0,4,0];
ix=logical(X);
Y = X(ix);
ixc=cumsum(ix);
Z=[zeros(1,sum(~logical(ixc))) Y(ixc(logical(ixc)))];
```

This does the trick, but it seems like an overly complicated solution to a simple problem, so can anyone help me with a better one? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a somewhat simpler version using cumsum:

```
X=[0,0,2,0,5,0,0,0,4,0];

%# find the entries where X is different from zero
id = find(X); 

%# If we want to run cumsum on X directly, we'd 
%# have the problem that the non-zero entry to the left
%# be added to subsequent non-zero entries. Thus, 
%# subtract the non-zero entries from their neighbor 
%# to the right 
X(id(2:end)) = X(id(2:end)) - X(id(1:end-1));

%# run cumsum to fill in values from the left
Y = cumsum(X)

Y =
     0     0     2     2     5     5     5     5     4     4
```

Comment: I agree, it is a slight improvement to my version. I'll keep the question open a little while longer and see if I get any alternative solutions, else I will accept this. Thanks.

Comment: Going with this version. Thank you! To 'improve' the solution a little bit more, you can obviously change the 3rd line to `X(id(2:end)) = diff(X(id));` :-)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a little something I wrote up. Does this do the trick?

```
% INPUT: the array you would like to populate
% OUTPUT: the populated array

function popArray = populate(array)

popArray = array;

% Loops through all the array elements and if it equals zero, replaces it
% with the previous element
%
% Since there is no element before the first to potentially populate it, this
% starts with the second element.
for ii = 2:length(popArray)
    if array(ii) == 0;
        popArray(ii)= popArray(ii-1);
    end
end

disp(popArray);
```

Comment: I find this a lot more readable than the OP's solution; it would be interesting to compare their speed, in case this is an issue here?

Comment: Thanks. I'd quite like to stay away from looping. My actual vectors/matrices are much larger than in this example so performance is a factor.

Comment: you're right. loops in matlab aren't optimal. no sense in not trying to help though. i'll keep thinking it through with arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Let me suggest another vectorized solution (though I like the one by [@Jonas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7348615/matlab-fill-previous-value-if-missing-value-or-zero/7349744#7349744) better):

```
X = [0 0 2 0 5 0 0 0 4 0]

id = find(X);
X(id(1):end) = cell2mat( arrayfun(@(a,b)a(ones(1,b)), ...
    X(id), [diff(id) numel(X)-id(end)+1], 'UniformOutput',false) )
```

Comment: Nice one, but I think that I agree that @Jonas has the preferred solution so far. Thanks.